# POST json data via ajax sends an empty array

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json

I'm trying to post data via ajax, this is my info:

```
    var jsondata =
                {"address" : [
                { "id": addid, "streetaddress": streetaddress, "city": city, "state": state,  "zipcode": zipcode, "latitude": latitude},
            ]   
            };  

    var jsontosend = JSON.stringify(jsondata, null, 2);
```

ajax function:

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: jsontosend,
                success: function(msg){
                   alert(msg);
                          }
             });

            return false;

            alert('Data sent');
```

}

on the php end, when i print_r($_POST) it just says

```
    array(0) {
    }
```

I'm alerting (jsontosend) and its showing me everything perfectly, as well as in firebug using post mothod, its showing all the params sent in a perfect clean manner.

The only way it passes any data is if I use GET method.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  adding POST data from firebug.
this is whats being alerted from the alert function:

```
    {"address":[{"id":1473294,"streetaddress":"3784 Howard Ave","city":"Washington DC","state":"DC","zipcode":20895,"latitude":39.027820587}]}
```

this is what firebug is showing as whats being passed when using POST method:

```
    myData=%7B%0A++++%22address%22%3A+%5B%0A++++++++%7B%0A++++++++++++%22id%22%3A+76076%2C%0A++++++++++++%22streetaddress%22%3A+%223784+Howard+Ave%22%2C%0A++++++++++++%22city%22%3A+%22Washington+DC%22%2C%0A++++++++++++%22state%22%3A+%22DC%22%2C%0A++++++++++++%22zipcode%22%3A+20895%2C%0A++++++++++++%22latitude%22%3A+39.027820587%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%5D%0A%7D
```

and this is the response for var_dump of $_POST:

```
    array(0) {
```

}

this is a var_dump of $_POST['myData']

```
    NULL
```

Comment: Do you have any "occasional" redirects before the posted data reaches php script?

Comment: I dont think so, Im not sure I fully understand what you mean though.

Comment: "when i print_r..." what do you mean? opening this page in your browser?

Comment: firebug shows you all the responses from the php script being called.

Comment: @Mike          I mean any 302 redirect on the server side? It will loose the post data. What do you have in $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']?

Comment: no there aren't any redirects,  request_method = post

Comment: @Cheery This is actually what was wrong here, it was configured to target http:, we only do https so everything redirected. THANKS OBAMA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm skeptical of the way you're using the contentType property.  Try taking out contentType.  The default content type is
application/x-www-form-urlencoded (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Also, use something like {mydata: jsontosend} for your data property.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {mydata: jsontosend},
            success: function(msg){
               alert(msg);
                      }
         });
```

Comment: it was content type! this is a nightmare!

Comment: 5 hours wasted on this because of something as stupid as content type!  it looks terrible still, but I haven't had a chance to add stripslashes yet.

Comment: Ironically I actually just tried that before I saw your answer and it worked.  But your answer is most definitely what it was! Thanks

Comment: I think you were just fetching it wrong from the php page! Read my comment below

Comment: @Mike sorry to hear that.  Glad you figured it out on your own!

Comment: Prefer this answer because contentType seems to be not a strong answer to the problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl

Comment: @StevenWexler - This worked for me. Had the same problem with exactly the above contentType +1

Answer (score 2):

Use

`data:{myData: jsontosend}`

It should send myData as a parameter in your request.

Comment: I've tried, in different combinations, with and without "" around mydata and it still returns an empty array.

Comment: Hey have you tried fetching the data from the php input data stream?
`<?php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($data);
?>`

Comment: When you use the JSON content-type, on the PHP side, it's necessary to manually read the JSON string directly from the request body using the php://input stream.

Comment: I haven't tried that, but removing the content type fixed it.

Comment: I just tested your method, (copy/pasting your code exactly), it returned null

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't understand application/json requests (by default). 
See this question: [How to post JSON to PHP with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl)

Answer (score 2):

I found that the comment provided by dkulkarni was the best solution here. It is necessary to read directly from the input stream to get POST data of any complexity. Changing the value of `$.ajax({contentType: ''})` did not work for me..

In order to troubleshoot this problem I had set up a controller method to echo back the JSON I was posting to my server. Changing the ContentType header made no difference. 
But after reading dkulkarni's comment I changed my server code from this:

```
    return $_POST;
```

to this:

```
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    return json_decode($data);
```

It worked perfectly.

Comment: This is utter genius. THANK YOU!!!! Thanks to dkulkami for the comment, and thanks to you for making the solution more obvious by this answer. I had been at it HOURS trying to work out why $_POST was empty...

Answer (score 1):

As dkulkarni commented in his post (Jan 24 at 7:53), the only way to retrieve JSON sent with Content-Type application/json seems to be to retrieve it directly from the input stream.

I made a lot of tests with different approaches, but always when I set Content-Type to JSON, the $_POST in PHP is empty.

My problem is I need to set Content-Type to JSON, because the server (where I don't have access) expects it, otherwise it returns unsupported datatype. I suppose they are retrieving directly from input stream.

Why I have to reproduce that in own PHP file? Because I need to make a proxy for testing issues, but thats not the point of this thread.

Comment: can't you leave datatype: "JSON" and still remove content-type? Thats what I did and it works perfectly.  Though it took hours of pulling my hair out before I saw Steven Wexler's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Taking contentType out is not a good idea. You DO want to send this data in JSON format. Key is to do what has been mentioned above, instead of trying to access the data on the receiving end (the target php file) with $data= $_POST it is critical to use $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

Here is an example of the entire round trip for a scenario with php and knockout.js:

JS (on requesting page):

```
function() {
   var payload = ko.toJSON({ YOUR KNOCKOUT OBJECT });
   jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'target.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: payload,
            datatype: "json",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
 };
```

And then in target.php (the page receiving the request):

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$payload_jsonDecoded = json_decode($data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ' dataType: "JSON" ' from the ajax request and check.